# How to call engClose() from Matlab C API and wait for its process to be closed?

Tags: c, matlab

I am using [MATLAB C API](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-programs-1.html) to run some scripts and generate some Simulink models. The problem is that, when I finish the work with MATLAB, I call:

```
engClose(instance);
```

to close the MATLAB engine. But it seems that after calling the `engClose` method, MATLAB has still exclusive access to the generated files and I cannot use the files just after calling this method. Putting a sleep for 2-3 seconds after this method, fixes everything.

I checked the `engClose` documentation [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/engclose.html). The documentation describes that:

> This routine sends a quit command to the MATLAB engine session and
>   closes the connection.

Does this description mean that the `engClose` method does not wait for the MATLAB process to be closed? If yes, is there any other way to wait for the MATLAB to be closed completely?

**Update 1:** My application has been developed with C++11, but this MATLAB interoperability part has written with C and MATLAB C API a long time ago. The target platform of the application is both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Maybe in C can you check if the MATLAB process is still alive?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is possible that a solution be platform-dependent. So it's best if you include that information in your question too. Also, I added the C tag, but it is possible that you're programming in C++. Please fix up the tags to include the language you're using to control MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Updated the info needed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I see that in MATLAB C++ API, there is a similar API that is called terminate. Does this method behave the same as engClose? Or it waits for the MATLAB process to be closed?

Comment: @Gupta: I have very little experience using the MATLAB engine interface. And I have never used the C++ API. But I imagine it's the same thing, you send the command to MATLAB to close, but MATLAB takes a while to close. I assume there's a way on Linux to monitor the MATLAB process and see when it's finished, and a different way on Windows to do the same. Or maybe you can monitor the file, to see when it's locks are freed.

Comment: @Anthony there may be lots of matlab processes. Which one should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some days of investigation, I found that there is no standard way for closing Matlab synchronously. But what you can do is to try to close ALL the:

1. open files (call `fclose all` to close all open files)
2. classes and functions (call `clear classes` or `clear functions`, respectively. You can call `clear all` for clearing everything.)

before calling `engClose`.

In addition, make sure that you call `rmpath(...)`for every path that you have added to Matlab search path.

If you clean the Matlab process properly before calling its `engClose` method, then calling an asynchronous Matlab `engClose` will be fine.

Comment: `clear` doesn't close classes and functions. It just removes all variables from the current workspace. `clear functions` clears functions from memory, and `clear classes` clears variables, functions and class definitions. Neither of these options will make MATLAB release open file handles. Removing directories from MATLAB's path should no do this either. However, if you have a MEX-file or an M-file that holds on to resources (using `persistent` variables, for example), then clearing those would help. But if they're `mlock`ed, you need to `munlock` them before you can `clear` them.

Comment: Also, `fclose all` will close all files opened with `fopen`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the comments. I applied them into my answer. Actually, in my implementation, I found that if I do not call `clear classes`, my mexfiles cannot be moved by my program. So, I recommenced this step to do. In addition, I found that if a directory is in MATLAB path list, you can remove it by windows explorer, but you cannot remove it problematically!!! (e.g. using `QDir::rmdir`). You can give it a check yourself.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am using Matlab R2017b.

Comment: OK. Windows is weird... :)  None of this would be necessary in Linux or MacOS.